# Why async await returning promise object not my own value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an event on select and in this select I need to get a function called `init();`

The `init()` function calls another function, `getManifestJsonFilePath()`.

In `getManifestJsonFilePath()` I need to check whether it has the same object in a json file which has already been declared and returning that same value.

In `init()` I also need to declare `getManifestJsonFilePath()`'s returned value to variable. Yet unfortunately the `getManifestJsonFilePath()` function is returning the following:

> Promise {: undefined};

```js
$('#city').change(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#bookingSearchBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
  manifestJsonFile = "/json/r" + city.val() + "-c1.json";
  // console.log(getManifestJsonFilePath(manifestJsonFile));

  init();
});
async function getManifestJsonFilePath(filename, path = 'build') {
  await manifestFile; //json file which need to be uploaded
  manifestFileResponse = manifestFile.responseJSON;
  $.each(manifestFileResponse, function(i, item) {
    if (i === filename) {
      return item;
    }
  });
}
let gettingJson;

async function init() {
  await getManifestJsonFilePath(manifestJsonFile);
  urlJson = getManifestJsonFilePath(manifestJsonFile);
  await urlJson;
  console.log(urlJson);
}
```

Comment: As you see I am using aync await not promise pls help me. I cannot understand why it is returning promise

Comment: Try changing your init function calls to `async function init(){
    let urlJson =  await getManifestJsonFilePath(manifestJsonFile);
   
    console.log(urlJson);

}`

Comment: async/ await will return promise object only, you have to handle it. when you make a ajax call -- promise ensure that call is completed and have status of success or failure, so you can handle next function !

Answer (score 0):

Here I have solved the problem first getManifestJsonFilePath() function may not be asynchronous because it works after changing select manifestFile has been uploaded while page reloading. so here is the code:

```
    city.change(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();     
                $('#bookingSearchBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                manifestJsonFile = "/json/r" + city.val() + "-c1.json"; 
                // console.log(getManifestJsonFilePath(manifestJsonFile));
                init();
            });
    async function init(){
                await getManifestJsonFilePath(manifestJsonFile);
                urlJson = getManifestJsonFilePath(manifestJsonFile);
                console.log(urlJson);
            }
```

the problem was with each I have returned value only in each and each function give value
to item more than 1 times and I have dicided solving it in a simple following way

```
function getManifestJsonFilePath(filename, path = 'build')
            {
                manifestFileResponse = manifestFile.responseJSON;
                let fileName;
                $.each(manifestFileResponse, function(i, item){
                    if (i === filename){
                        fileName = item
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        fileName = "false message"
                    }
                });
                return fileName

            }
```